# deriving multiple variables when one variable is equal to another

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was pondering and came across this. I don't understand what is wrong just know that something is

$$
\frac{d}{dx} wx = w 
$$
that is fine. but in the case:
$$
w = x 
$$
then
$$
wx = x^2 \\
$$
so
$$
\frac{d}{dx}wx = \frac{d}{dx}x^2 = 2x
$$
but
$$w \neq 2x$$
as
$$x \neq 2x$$

I have come to the conclusion that $\frac{d}{dx}wx \neq \frac{d}{dx}x^2 $ when $w = x$ but why?

Comment: By "deriving" do you mean "differentiating" in your title?

Comment: This is where we need the concept of partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w=x$, it is no longer a constant, but a function of $x$, and to derive $wx$ w.r.t. $x$ you should apply, for instance, the product rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}wx = w'x + wx'= x + w = x+x = 2x.
$$